# React props not satisfying type constraints but no type error is thrown

Tags: reactjs, typescript

If you consider this code:

```js
type A = {
  kind: 'a'
  other?: undefined
}

type B = {
  kind: 'b'
  other: number
}

type Kind = A | B

function inspect(obj:Kind) {

}

inspect({ kind: 'a', other: 44 })
```

^ This throws an error because kind "a" cannot have the `other` property set to a number.

```js
inspect({ kind: 'b' })
```

^ This also throws an error because kind "b" requires the `other` property to be a number.

```js
inspect({ kind: 'b', other: 44 })
```

^ this last one is OK. [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUDWBLAdgEwC4oByAQ2LSgHtgALCAJwH4iBXfCAM1wjxQF8UKUJCgAhBMkrZ8RYgCMK6GvQZEcrALbzGAoSOgBpXHklwAPuKGd2AY2BYqOKLgDOkewAoq8gFYFjfABKKT0UNw9gTyRMEzlyABpqOkYiABY0qH4goA)

All of that is how I would expect it to behave but I am trying to do the same thing with a react component.

I want a callback handler that accepts either "new user data" or "edit user data" but if the handler accepts edit user data, then an existing user must be required. Or if the handler accepts new user data, then no user should be passed in.

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react'

type User = {
  name: string
  id: string
}

type NewUser = {
  name: string
  pswd: string
}

type EditUser = {
  name: string
}

export type UserFormHandler<T>  = (data: T) => Promise<void>

type NewUserFormProps = {
  onSubmit: UserFormHandler<NewUser>
  user?: undefined
}

type EditUserFormProps = {
  onSubmit: UserFormHandler<EditUser>
  user: User
}

type UserFormProps = NewUserFormProps | EditUserFormProps

const UserForm:FC<UserFormProps> = props => {
  return null
}

const Usage:FC = props => {
  const onSubmit:UserFormHandler<EditUser> = () => Promise.resolve()
  return (
    <UserForm onSubmit={onSubmit} />
  )
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwnAL5wBmUEIcA5FKhrQFDMwCeYScAqgM5IocALy5mcOADsUIJAC44fGFGCSA5uLjAAJgqUr1zEqw5c4AOSQB3foJFiJ02XuWqNEsHyu7Frw8bZObgBRbWAYWyFRHE0neV8DDQCkAA9IWDhTbkj8aBAACRRJbQAbQQAeABUAPglRAAptFBgUBUqAShFagAUqEGABcoA3CB1qkyCLaxy83ohPexiJCEkAZQBXACN+mAUZqAKi0orLGwEocYl184B+BXXipHJVJG0jCbNQ8P2QOYXozQrDbbcJ7c65A6FYplKDlL4Rc6XODXQRgwTvQJmH5-Pj2U7YqgLAA+cHhBPmfFYaBWSl44LyciI5XJnlqojAhNxwlqSzgDBg6ygkik6xKJQx1MktP4KDU8iI9g5FK6DjgktpQK2OzkPyhx1hZMR9nqnW5cDm-QEADoGHwICUhkgTZp+YLhfVNBJmfSDnBNSCYMIcP6dmQAPRI9pGIA)

I am doing the same thing here and making the same mistake. My props do not match because I am passing an edit user handler, but no user to accompany it. Yet it does NOT throw a type error here. I am trying to understand why that is, and how to fix it?

Comment: `UseFormHandler<EditUser>` is assignable to `UseFormHandler<NewUser>`. Therefore, TypeScript believes it satisfies `NewUserFormProps` and does not error. If you are confused why this is the case, functions are **contravariant** with respect to their parameters.

Comment: @katniss "functions are contravariant with respect to their parameters" yep, I think that is what was confusing me.